# Hyphens getting replaced with Question Marks in SQL & Date is stored as NULL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, localhost

Suppose I have an INSERT statement as:

```
INSERT INTO student(stdNo, stdFirstName, stdLastName, stdJoinDate)
VALUES ('901‐23‐4567','Harry','Potter', '2014-05-15');
```

But when viewed in localhost/phpmyadmin, the stdNo gets stored as `901?23?4567`.
Also when I try to store `DATE`, it's being stored as `0000-00-00`.
Can someone please help me with these?

Answer (score 0):

In your localhost in phpmyadmin in Student table please check the **Collation Property** and make it **utf8_general_ci**, then it should work.

Today i had the same issue, and found this question by searching for the answer. And fortunately i solved my issue so thought to help you back.

Thank You